# Paypal Adaptive Payments - How to change business name on Return URL and Cancel URL

Tags: paypal-adaptive-payments

I have implemented Paypal Adaptive payments, having my business Mersica Inc. as the secondary receiver and another business (Fatpaint) as primary receiver, but still, Paypal shows my business name (Mersica Inc) in the Cancel URL and Return URL even though I have set the business name to "Fatpaint" via DisplayOptions. How can I prevent my business name from appearing?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

frontend code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="business_name" value="<%= Global.BusinessName %>" />
```

server side code:

```
//check the payment_status is Completed
//check that txn_id has not been previously processed
//check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email

// pull the values passed on the initial message from PayPal    
NameValueCollection args = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(strResponse_copy);
//string payment_stat = args["payment_status"];    
if (strResponse == "VERIFIED")) {
        string trans_id = args["txn_id"];
        string invoice_id = args["business_name"];        
        string invoice_id = args["invoice"];
        string trans_date = args["payment_date"];
        string item_name = args["item_name"];
    ........
}
.................
```